# Contract Testing with Pact in Angular with Karma is filing with error - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@pact-foundation/pact-web

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, pact

I am trying to write contract tests using below libraries -

- [Pact Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pact-foundation/pact-node) - Latest version - v10.17.7
- [Karma Pact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pact-foundation/karma-pact) - Latest version - v3.1.0
- [Pact Web](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pact-foundation/pact-web) - Latest version - v9.18.1

But every time I run the test `ng test`, I get below error -

```
INFO [karma-pact]: Starting Pact Mock Server...
ERROR [karma-pact]: Failed to start Pact Mock Server Error: Couldn't start Pact with PID: 18860`
```

With lot of trial-errors and spending plenty of time -

- I found that below libraries are missing in `node_modules` folder
  -- `node-addon-api`
  -- `node-gyp-build`
- When I add those, it starts Pact Mock Server successfully!
- Not sure why those libraries are not getting installed when I do `npm install` at first place!

Now with above in place, Pact Server is successfully started -

```
INFO [karma-pact]: Starting Pact Mock Server...
INFO [karma-pact]: Pact Mock Server running on port: 1234
```

Further, I still get below error and unable to proceed further -

```
./src/app/services/user.service.pact.spec.ts:4:0-62 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@pact-foundation/pact-web' in 'C:\angular-pact\src\app\services'
```

You can find my code here in GitHub Repo - [angular-pact](https://github.com/subodhgodbole/angular-pact).

I tried -

- Searching internet with this problem, but did not receive any clues.
- Installing few older versions of said `Pact` libraries, but that also did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really suggest not using Karma (or Pact Web) any longer. They are essentially deprecated and will receive no further updates.

If you're only just getting started, best to use Jest/Mocha/etc. with the usual `@pact-foundation/pact` library.

See https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/626 for more.

Comment: Thanks @matthew-fellows for reply and suggestion.
I agree with you, moving away from Karma and using something like Jest is the way forward.

However, we are just starting with contract testing and wanted to use Pact, but our project is not new. So we are already using Karma, and moving to Jest is not yet scoped at product planning. So it might take time to go to ideal state. Meanwhile we wanted to start with Contract Testing.

Hence I am still looking for clues to get me further with Pact Web and Karma Pact.

Comment: Pact Web and Karma Pact are just deprecated, so I was hopping it will work out of the box. But unfortunately for me it turns out to be otherwise!

Comment: Hmm... I guess last resort for me is to add `Jest` into my project and use it with Pact, but not remove `Karma` yet since it's used by so many tests already. But this way my project will have 2 testing frameworks at same time!